# I have CustomSharedClassLoader in Tomcat7 for shared lib. We migrated to tomcat9, it is not working. How to achieve the same functionality in tomcat9

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat8, tomcat9

I have Custom SharedClassLoader in Tomcat 7 to load shared library jars, which is used by different applications in that tomcat. We migrated to Tomcat 9, now it is not working. How to achieve the same functionality in tomcat 9.

In Tomcat 9 it expects resources to be passed. I don't find any sample Code on how to populate resources.

I tried like below

```
public CustomSharedClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) throws Exception {
        super(parent);

//The below three lines are added by me to work for Tomcat 9.        
        StandardRoot standardRoot = new StandardRoot();
        standardRoot.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet());
        setResources(standardRoot);
// End for tomcat 9 changes.

        for (URL urlForJars : getClassPath(SHARED_LIB)) {
            addURL(urlForJars);
        }
        start();
    }
```

It didn't work.

```
public class CustomSharedClassLoader extends WebappClassLoader{
//Which takes shared folder libarary, it returns those classes.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add shared classes in [catalina.properties](https://github.com/diplomatiegouvfr/tomcat8-instance/blob/master/tomcat8-instance-8.0.28/usr/share/tomcat8/skel/conf/catalina.properties)

> ```
> shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/classes,${catalina.home}/shared/*.jar
> ```

Doc:

> ```
> # List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "shared"
> # classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
> # Path may be relative to the CATALINA_BASE path or absolute. If left as blank,
> # the "common" loader will be used as Catalina's "shared" loader.
> # Examples:
> #     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
> #     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
> #                  repositories
> #     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
> # Please note that for single jars, e.g. bar.jar, you need the URL form
> # starting with file:.
> ```

Comment: We have listener which lies in tomcat\lib folder, which access the classes using this SharedClassLoader. This listener class is also in lib folder, which loads jars from tomcat\shared folder. If I use this shared.loader, listener can't access the classes in the shared folder.